# var defined inside a function is still accessible outside of the function in clojure, why?

Tags: clojure, scheme

In Clojure REPL:

```
user> (defn add [x y] (def foo :defined-inside) (+ x y))
#'user/add
user> foo
#object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x63a0ad69 "Unbound: #'user/foo"]
user> (add 1 1)
2
user> foo
:defined-inside
```

Apparently, I think `foo` shouldn't be accessible outside `add`, Why Clojure allow this, which is different from other lisp (eg. scheme) ?

Comment: Other lisp... CL `defparameter`, `defun`, `defvar` creates top level bindings. Scheme is the only one that has this strange feature that `define` inside a `lambda` is handled by the `lambda` macro (and rewritten to `letrec` which eventually turns into `lambda` forms) while top level `define` is handled by its own macro.

Comment: @Sylwester For me, I think this is a bad idea for which it can pollute the global env, and Scheme is the right way to go.

Comment: You never polute since you don't use `def` if you want a local variable or function, Same with Common Lisp. It's the same as in Scheme with **less confusion** (since you might have had the impression that `define` works the same top level as in a `let`, but it's done by two completely different parts of the implementation that have nothing to do with each other other than the name clash)

Answer (score 2):

`def` is always global in Clojure, unlike some other Lisps.

To create local symbol bindings within a function, use `let`.

Comment: Why Clojure is designed in this way, any reasons ? For me, I think this is a bad idea for which it can pollute the global env.

Comment: Because Clojure likes to give you enough rope to hang yourself. Sometimes it's a lot easier to use all kinds of weird side effects; you have to clearly mean it, but by golly Rich Hickey will let you do it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure you can use `let` to define local vriables:

```
(defn add [x y] 
  (let [foo :defined-inside] 
    (+ x y)))
```

It can even work for local functions:

```
(defn add [x y]
  (let [foo (fn [x y] (+ x y))]
    (foo x y)))
```

But for mutual recursive functions you need to use `letfn`:

```
(defn is-odd? [n]
  (letfn [(is-even? [n]
            (if (zero? n)
                true
                (is-odd? (dec n))))
          (is-odd? [n]
            (if (zero? n)
                false
                (is-even? (dec n))))]
    (is-odd? n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Def that is inside function is useful, when I want to create a bind in the global var *lazily* by calling function.

```
(defn initialize-browser []
    (def browser (run-browser)))
```

For example, I have used this pattern to run the browser with selenium.
I can easily control the state of browser. 
if I don't want to run browser, I don't call the function. When I want to run and handle a browser, I call this function only once, and handle by other functions.